# Getting username (or directory) through sockets (Python)

Tags: python, linux, sockets, server, tcp

Context: There is a python coding assignment being made that will be uploaded on a course server. Each student will have their own account on this server, and hence their own home directory where they will run their code. They will be able to connect to a different program on the same server through sockets. The program they connect to will be running 24/7 and is common to all of them.

The situation is that we want to keep track of what messages are being sent to this common program and by whom. Is there a way, through sockets or anything, to be able to identify where this message came from (which user or which directory). We have a python program they use to send messages to the common program but if we hardcode the student ID, they can still change the code. They have their own username and password for the course server so I was hoping I could incorporate their linux username somehow. What would be the best way to achieve what I need?

Comment: can't you ask students to enter their username into your program and whenever they send a message from that program, it also sends a log entry to server with time, message and their username

Comment: We don't want them to be able to lie about their username

Comment: It's not possible to get this information from socket. Socket address is a combination of IP address  and Port number. As a workaround, you could assign a unique key to each student and ask them to add it to the message to identify the message. This key should not be shared with others and be treated like a password. This key can be generated using base64, md5, sha256, etc or even using a more complex PKI infrastructure.